# Trying to read out a MAX-M8Q GNSS HAT on a Raspberry Pi 5, issue with python code?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gps

I recently bought a MAX-M8Q GNSS HAT and a Raspberry Pi 5. When trying to execute the demo code, which tries to read out the data provided by the sensor, i always get the message "Module not ready, try moving the antenna to outdoors". However, when  connecting the GPS module to my PC and after installing the appropriate driver and software (u-blox), it works just fine and outputs all the data i was expecting.

I suspected that the error does not lie within the GPS module (since it does provide info to my PC), but rather within the python script which reads out the data on my Raspberry Pi,  which you can see here:

```
from gps3 import agps3
import coordTransform_py.coordTransform_utils as transform 
import time

#GPSDSocket creates a GPSD socket connection & request/retrieve GPSD output.
gps_socket = agps3.GPSDSocket()
#DataStream unpacks the streamed gpsd data into python dictionaries.
data_stream = agps3.DataStream()
gps_socket.connect()
gps_socket.watch()

gcj02_lng_lat = [0.0,0.0]
bd09_lng_lat = [0.0,0.0]

print('gps device make wgs84 coordinate\r\ngcj02 coordinate is for amap or google map\r\nbd09 coordinate is for baidu map\r\n\033[1;31m Please press Ctrl+c if want to exit \033[0m')
for new_data in gps_socket:
    if new_data:
        data_stream.unpack(new_data)
        if data_stream.lat != 'n/a' and data_stream.lon != 'n/a':
            gcj02_lng_lat = transform.wgs84_to_gcj02(float(data_stream.lon),float(data_stream.lat))
            bd09_lng_lat = transform.wgs84_to_bd09(float(data_stream.lon),float(data_stream.lat))
            print('altitude       = ', data_stream.alt,'M',end='\r\n',flush=True) 
            print('wgs84 lon,lat  = ',data_stream.lon,',',data_stream.lat,end='\r\n',flush=True)                   
            print('google lon.lat = %.9f,%.9f' %(gcj02_lng_lat[1],gcj02_lng_lat[0]),end='\r\n',flush=True)         # google map could use
            print('amap lon.lat   = %.9f,%.9f' %(gcj02_lng_lat[0],gcj02_lng_lat[1]),end='\r\n',flush=True)         # amap soso map could use
            print('bd09 lon,lat   = %.9f,%.9f' %(bd09_lng_lat[0],bd09_lng_lat[1]),end='\r\n',flush=True)           # baidu map could use
            print('speed          = ', data_stream.speed,'KM/H',end='\r\n',flush=True)
            for i in range(0,10):
                print('update after {1} seconds'.format(10-i),end='\r',flush=True)
                time.sleep(1)
            print('\x1b[6A',end='\r')
        else:
            print('\033[1;32m Module not ready,please move the antenna to outdoors \033[0m',end='\r',flush=True)
```

I got it from the official [Waveshare Wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/MAX-M8Q_GNSS_HAT) on my GPS-HAT. In general, I kept to the instructions you can find on there (paragraph "Using with Raspberry Pi"), with the exception that I had to set up a virtual environment. That is due to the OS I am using on my Raspberry Pi (Debian Bookworm 64-bit). This OS requires me to use a virtual environment in order to install the gps3 package.

After downloading the gps, gps-clients and gps-tools packages with `sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients gpsd-tools` and after activating the virtual environment and installing the gps3 package with `pip3 install gps3` (since my OS does not let me do it system-wide with `sudo pip3 install gps3`), i still get the same message mentioned above. I also tried moving the python file as well as its dependencies into the virtual environment folder, but this also yielded no success. I also should mention that the serial port is enabled and i set the gpsd-Parameters to

```
USBAUTO="false"
DEVICES="/dev/ttyS0"
GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

My girlfriend suggested to append the missing `else` and add something to be printed in order to see whether the "error" occurs within the first or second if-statement. We did that, and the terminal always just displayed that message we added. I might be wrong on this, but it seems like the first if statement is never fulfilled, and since there was no else-condition to that statement, it always jumped to the else-condition of the second if-statement. My girlfriend then suspected, that `new_data` simply does not exist/is always empty, and hence the entire second if-statement can never run. Now, I am a newbie to python and Linux, having received this Raspberry Pi in the mail just last week. I have worked with R quite a bit in my studies, but this does not seem to help me here. My question is, how to I get this to work, and what is the reason it currently does not work?

Thanks a lot in advance!